# Storyboard/nib or not

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Recently I have been thinking maybe I should try out Storyboard in XCode.

I have always programmatically done my views in XCode since I didn't quite like the Interface Builder in the past. I wanted to know exactly what was happening in my apps, so I never really used any interface builders.

So I want to hear experiences of people who have used both, advantages and disadvantages.

I like managing all my UIViewControllers programmatically. But when I set up the UIViews, I kinda have to run my simulator multiple times to check if I have placed my view on the right pixel.

So I like the Interface Builders for the fact that I can see where my views will be positioned.

What do you think?

Comment: This is a valid beginners problem, and reaches into some other areas to, use a UI design tool, or handcode elements and wired them up 'manually'

Comment: Agree with Harald. Should not have been closed.

Comment: The reason I made this post is because when I was a beginner I couldn't really find any specific place to list the advantages and disadvantages of those 2 approaches. After so long, I tried searching again and nothing specific appeared. So I thought this would help a lot of people. But I understand SO's reasoning too.

Answer (score 2):

In the apps I have I actually use a combination of both.

If you're used to doing everything programatically then you will probably find it easier to start off with doing separate xibs.

Doing it that way means that any flow of the VCs is still done programatically like you are already doing.

The main advantage that you get from using a Storyboard is that you can create the flow of the app using IB as well as the UI of each VC.  Oh, you can also create custom UITableViewCells within the table it is related to also.

Once you have got used to doing everything with XIBs you should find it easy to move on to Storyboard stuff.

Having said that, there isn't a chain of... Code < XIBs < Storyboard.

They should be sued to complement each other.

I've made a few apps using Storyboards and they worked brilliantly. Just before Christmas I started another app and the requirements of the app lead me down a path of explicitly using XIBs and no storyboard at all.

I've also made apps where the majority of the app uses storyboard but then there are certain common places that all use the same VC or all use the same UIView subclass and for those I have created my own separate XIB files.

It really depends what you are doing but either way, if you can do it in code then most of the time it is actually a lot easier and just as powerful in IB.

(with the exclusion of View drawing etc...)

Answer (score 1):

The new StoryBoard interface is quite nice and intuitive. It still gives you fine-grained control however, without you needing to do everything programmatically. I think it is definitely much more efficient, and it might take about an hour to get used to it is definitely worth the time, from my perspective.

Answer (score 1):

For apps that see repeated interface tweaks Interface Builder has been such a time saver for me - especially for projects with picky clients. The learning curve isn't really that steep if you already know how to code the same things manually which it sounds like you do. I'd say go for it and you won't regret it. I haven't.